# DNS and mod_rewrite not-collaborating

Tags: domain-name-system, centos, mod-rewrite, bind

I have added a CNAME record to my DNS on my CentOS server to redirect subdomain.mydomain.com to another server.

I also use mod_rewrite to rewrite mydomain.com to www.mydomain.com:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

this is placed into .htaccess in the root public html directory

Now, the problem is that whenever I lookup subdomain.mydomain.com it redirects me to www.mydomain.com

I tried adding another RewriteCond:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^subdomain\.mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

But it didn't help...

Anyone has some ideas?

Comment: Is the CNAME record for subdomain.mydomain.com pointing to either mydomain.com or www.mydomain.com? Or is it pointing to some other domain entirely? If I understand your description correctly subdomain should never get to the mod_rewrite stuff. That means the problem is with the dns.

Comment: the CNAME record is pointing to another domain entirely

Comment: I just ran dig @ns1.mydomain.com subdomain.mydomain.com - the answer was correct from the dns

Comment: If you turn on rewrite logging, what do you see in the log file?

Comment: Do you have any /etc/hosts entries that may be causing problems?  Try the command `getent hosts subdomain.mydomain.com`.

Comment: You didn't accutal answer my question though.... is the final destination (IP address) of subdomain supposed to be the same as mydomain.com?

Comment: Ok, I have taken care of the problem, it was a simple DNS record syntax mistake :) thanks for your assistance! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

matthew was right, the request should never get to mod_rewrite with proper dns alias configuration. The problem was in a simple DNS record syntax mistake made accidentally when typing. It's now taken care of and working properly :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a redirect is happening in the web application.

- Try download static file(css,js,jpg,...) from subdomain.mydomain.com
- Use RewriteLog and RewriteLogLevel Directive for debug